# What is the difference between Modernizr's placeholder test and the input attributes test?

Tags: placeholder, modernizr

Modernizr includes an Input attributes test and a placeholder attribute test. This translates to Modernizr.placeholder and Modernizr.input.placeholder; which also includes other attribute tests on the input namespace. What is the difference between these two, if any? The documentation is not very descriptive.  The only difference that appears to be happening is that Modernizr.placeholder covers support for textarea elements whereas Modernizr.input.placeholder only tests for the attribute's validity on input elements. Please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much of a difference, but there is a small one. `placeholder` ensures that the `placeholder` attr works in inputs and textareas. `input.placeholder` only checks for placeholder support on an input element.

Comment: Thanks for confirming!